# change Userlogin block on header to custom

Tags: 7, users

How can we change userlogin block on header to custom, I am using D 7.9, theme : bartik, and how can i change the below userlogin block to custom block in image2 below.
And `login` button should take upto example.com/user and `signup` button should take out to register a new account

And image1

[image]

And image2

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need just to remove the login block and create for example a new menu or use the existing service navigation where you place the links to the login form and to the reigster form. Show this menu then in the place where the login-block was. Optionaly place a link to Logout too. Drupal will recognize if the user is logged in or not.